# Multiple roots of the likelihood equations vs. consistency

Tags: maximum-likelihood, small-sample, consistency

I'm trying to understand the implications of the [Huzurbazar](https://doi.org/10.1111/j.1469-1809.1947.tb02394.x)-[Chanda](https://doi.org/10.1093/biomet/41.1-2.56) theorem in finite samples. The result basically says that of all roots of the likelihood equations, one and only one tends in probability to the true parameter vector (i.e., is consistent).

Of course I'm aware that this is an asymptotic result, and in practice, likelihood equations often have multiple zeros. So what are, if any, the implications of this result in small samples? Does it mean the inconsistent roots will disappear as $n \to \infty$, or will they remain but there's only a single consistent one among them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can mean either.

Sometimes you have multiple roots and all but one of them diverge to infinity.  This happens for the Cauchy location family: multiple roots exist even asymptotically, but any bounded interval is eventually free of roots other than the consistent one.

You can also have multiple solutions for small $n$ but only one solution for large enough $n$.  One example is the correlation coefficient in a bivariate Normal distribution with both variances known and equal to 1.  The score equation is a cubic, and can have as many as three solutions for small samples, but will have only one real solution for large enough $n$ (according to https://www.jstor.org/stable/2676824)

Comment: Are there known cases for the latter (multiple roots in small samples which disappear as $n \to \infty$)?

Comment: I edited the answer to add an example